# Apply Quaternion Rotation to Vector

Tags: rotations, quaternions

Have done lot of googling on this and am overwhelmed by the number of formulas; not a math major, just a developer struggling to understand quaternion rotations:)

```
Given a vector of: 0, 0, 0.15
And a quaternion: 0.86671, -0.40654, -0.21285, 0.19555 (s, x, y, z)
Vector should equal: -0.07919, 0.09322, 0.08683
```

Any help to understand what formulas should be applied to get to this result is appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There is not enough data to answer the question. To represent rotation in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ using quaternions, you need at least one vector, a rotation axis and a rotation angle... Aka please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry was not able to provide more; the math for the results is done behind the scenes ... all I am given is the vector and quaternion doing (vector * rotation) to get the result, so was difficult to understand what was needed to math this. :<

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Formula**

The formula to calculatise would be
$$\mathrm{v}_{\text{rotated}} = \mathrm{q} \cdot \mathrm{v} \cdot \overline{\mathrm{q}}$$ with your vector $$\mathrm{v} = \left[\begin{matrix}0\\ 0\\ 0.15\end{matrix}\right] = 0 \cdot \mathrm{i} + 0 \cdot \mathrm{j} + 0.15 \cdot \mathrm{k}$$ and your quaternion $$\mathrm{q} = 0.86671 - 0.40654 \cdot \mathrm{i} - 0.21285 \cdot \mathrm{j} + 0.19555 \cdot \mathrm{k}$$ and $$\overline{\mathrm{q}} = 0.86671 + 0.40654 \cdot \mathrm{i} + 0.21285 \cdot \mathrm{j} - 0.19555 \cdot \mathrm{k}$$ with $\mathrm{i}^{2} = \mathrm{j}^{2} = \mathrm{k}^{2} = \mathrm{i} \cdot \mathrm{j} \cdot \mathrm{k} = -1$.

But don't forget that quaternions are not commutative with respect to multiplication.

**Formula with roationangle and rotationaxis**

If you use the vector / quaternion $r$ as the axis of rotation, $\varphi$ as the rotation angle, $\mathrm{v}$ as the vector to be rotated and the rotated vector $\mathrm{v}_{\text{rotated}}$, then the formula applies:
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{v}_{\text{rotated}} &= \mathrm{q} \cdot \mathrm{v} \cdot \overline{\mathrm{q}}\\
\mathrm{v}_{\text{rotated}} &= \left( \cos\left( \frac{\varphi}{2} \right) + \mathrm{u} \cdot \sin\left( \frac{\varphi}{2} \right) \right) \cdot \mathrm{v} \cdot \left( \cos\left( \frac{\varphi}{2} \right) - \mathrm{u} \cdot \sin\left( \frac{\varphi}{2} \right) \right)\\
\mathrm{v}_{\text{rotated}} &= \left( \cos\left( \frac{\varphi}{2} \right) + \frac{\mathrm{r}}{||\mathrm{r}||} \cdot \sin\left( \frac{\varphi}{2} \right) \right) \cdot \mathrm{v} \cdot \left( \cos\left( \frac{\varphi}{2} \right) - \frac{\mathrm{r}}{||\mathrm{r}||} \cdot \sin\left( \frac{\varphi}{2} \right) \right)\\
\end{align*}
$$

**Code**

Since you are a developer, my code for calculating rotation using quaternions might tell you more then the formulas:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Rotation</title>

    <script src="myscript.js"></script>
    <link href = "style.css" rel = "stylesheet"><link>
</head>

<body style = "margin: 0%;">
    <h1 style = "left: 10pt;">Rotation in ℝ³</h1>
    
    <div>
        <form id = "QuaternionversorImput">
            <label for = "QuaternionversorZ">Quaternion q: </label><br><br>
            <label for = "i">i-Im(q): </label>
            <input type = "text" id = "i" name = "i"><br><br>
            <label for = "j">j-Im(q): </label>
            <input type = "text" id = "j" name = "j"><br><br>
            <label for = "k">k-Im(q): </label>
            <input type = "text" id = "k" name = "k"><br><br>
            <label for = "Rotationaxis">Rotation Axis: </label><br><br>
            <label for = "Rotationaxis">x (Euler Axis): </label>
            <input type = "text" id = "i-Rotationaxis" name = "i-Rotationaxis"><br><br>
            <label for = "Rotationaxis">y (Euler Axis): </label>
            <input type = "text" id = "j-Rotationaxis" name = "j-Rotationaxis"><br><br>
            <label for = "Rotationaxis">z (Euler Axis): </label>
            <input type = "text" id = "k-Rotationaxis" name = "k-Rotationaxis"><br><br>
            <input type = "button" onclick = "calculate()" onclick = "plot()" value="Calculate (φ in °)!">
            <input type = "button" onclick = "calculate2()" value="Calculate (φ in rad)!">
        </form>

        <form id = "Rotation">
            <label for = "Rotationangleφ">Rotationangle φ: </label><br><br>
            <label for = "Rotationangleindegree">Rotationangle: </label>
            <input type = "text" id = "Rotationangleindegree" name = "Rotationangleindegree"><br><br>
        </form>

        <div id = "RotatedQuaternionversor">
            Rotated Quaternion q':</div>
            <div id = "RotatedQuaternionversorImi">
            </div>
            <div id = "RotatedQuaternionversorImj">
            </div>
            <div id = "RotatedQuaternionversorImk">
            </div>
            <div id = "x">
                i-Im(q'): </div>
                <div id = "y">
                    j-Im(q'): </div>
                    <div id = "z">
                        k-Im(q'): </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
function calculate() {
    let q_rotatedi = document.getElementById('RotatedQuaternionversorImi');
    let q_rotatedj = document.getElementById('RotatedQuaternionversorImj');
    let q_rotatedk = document.getElementById('RotatedQuaternionversorImk');
    let y_0 = 0
    let y_1 = document.getElementById("i").value;
    let y_2 = document.getElementById("j").value;
    let y_3 = document.getElementById("k").value;
    let i_r = document.getElementById("i-Rotationaxis").value;
    let j_r = document.getElementById("j-Rotationaxis").value;
    let k_r = document.getElementById("k-Rotationaxis").value;
    let bet_r = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(i_r, 2) + Math.pow(j_r, 2) + Math.pow(k_r, 2));
    let Rotationangle = document.getElementById("Rotationangleindegree").value;
    let x_0 = Math.cos(Rotationangle / 2 * Math.PI / 180);
    let x_1 = Math.sin(Rotationangle / 2 * Math.PI / 180) * i_r / bet_r;
    let x_2 = Math.sin(Rotationangle / 2 * Math.PI / 180) * j_r / bet_r;
    let x_3 = Math.sin(Rotationangle / 2 * Math.PI / 180) * k_r / bet_r;
    let result1 = -(x_0 * y_0 - x_1 * y_1 - x_2 * y_2 - x_3 * y_3) * x_1 + (x_0 * y_1 + x_1 * y_0 + x_2 * y_3 - x_3 * y_2) * x_0 - (x_0 * y_2 - x_1 * y_3 + x_2 * y_0 + x_3 * y_1) * x_3 + (x_0 * y_3 + x_1 * y_2 - x_2 * y_1 + x_3 * y_0) * x_2;
    let result2 = -(x_0 * y_0 - x_1 * y_1 - x_2 * y_2 - x_3 * y_3) * x_2 + (x_0 * y_1 + x_1 * y_0 + x_2 * y_3 - x_3 * y_2) * x_3 + (x_0 * y_2 - x_1 * y_3 + x_2 * y_0 + x_3 * y_1) * x_0 - (x_0 * y_3 + x_1 * y_2 - x_2 * y_1 + x_3 * y_0) * x_1;
    let result3 = (x_0 * y_0 - x_1 * y_1 - x_2 * y_2 - x_3 * y_3) * x_3 - (x_0 * y_1 + x_1 * y_0 + x_2 * y_3 - x_3 * y_2) * x_2 + (x_0 * y_2 - x_1 * y_3 + x_2 * y_0 + x_3 * y_1) * x_1 + (x_0 * y_3 + x_1 * y_2 - x_2 * y_1 + x_3 * y_0) * x_0;
    q_rotatedi.textContent = result1;
    q_rotatedj.textContent = result2;
    q_rotatedk.textContent = result3;
}
function calculate2() {
    let q_rotatedi = document.getElementById('RotatedQuaternionversorImi');         // x-Rotationsvektorpart
    let q_rotatedj = document.getElementById('RotatedQuaternionversorImj');         // y-Rotationsvektorpart
    let q_rotatedk = document.getElementById('RotatedQuaternionversorImk');         // z-Rotationsvektorpart
    let y_0 = 0;                                                                    // da 3D keine (4-1)D-Zahl
    let y_1 = document.getElementById("i").value;                                   // x-Urvektorpart
    let y_2 = document.getElementById("j").value;                                   // y-Urvektorpart
    let y_3 = document.getElementById("k").value;                                   // z-Urvektorpart
    let i_r = document.getElementById("i-Rotationaxis").value;                      // x-Euler'sche-Achse
    let j_r = document.getElementById("j-Rotationaxis").value;                      // y-Euler'sche-Achse
    let k_r = document.getElementById("k-Rotationaxis").value;                      // z-Euler'sche-Achse
    let bet_r = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(i_r, 2) + Math.pow(j_r, 2) + Math.pow(k_r, 2));  // Betrah der Rotationsachse
    let Rotationangle = document.getElementById("Rotationangleindegree").value;     // Rotationswinkel
    let x_0 = Math.cos(Rotationangle / 2);                                          // w-Komponente
    let x_1 = Math.sin(Rotationangle / 2) * i_r / bet_r;                            // Einheitsquaternion x-Komponente (da x_1 = x-Euler'sche-Achse / ||Rotationsachse||)
    let x_2 = Math.sin(Rotationangle / 2) * j_r / bet_r;                            // Einheitsquaternion y-Komponente (da x_2 = y-Euler'sche-Achse / ||Rotationsachse||)
    let x_3 = Math.sin(Rotationangle / 2) * k_r / bet_r;                            // Einheitsquaternion z-Komponente (da x_3 = z-Euler'sche-Achse / ||Rotationsachse||)
    let result1 = -(x_0 * y_0 - x_1 * y_1 - x_2 * y_2 - x_3 * y_3) * x_1 + (x_0 * y_1 + x_1 * y_0 + x_2 * y_3 - x_3 * y_2) * x_0 - (x_0 * y_2 - x_1 * y_3 + x_2 * y_0 + x_3 * y_1) * x_3 + (x_0 * y_3 + x_1 * y_2 - x_2 * y_1 + x_3 * y_0) * x_2;
    let result2 = -(x_0 * y_0 - x_1 * y_1 - x_2 * y_2 - x_3 * y_3) * x_2 + (x_0 * y_1 + x_1 * y_0 + x_2 * y_3 - x_3 * y_2) * x_3 + (x_0 * y_2 - x_1 * y_3 + x_2 * y_0 + x_3 * y_1) * x_0 - (x_0 * y_3 + x_1 * y_2 - x_2 * y_1 + x_3 * y_0) * x_1;
    let result3 = (x_0 * y_0 - x_1 * y_1 - x_2 * y_2 - x_3 * y_3) * x_3 - (x_0 * y_1 + x_1 * y_0 + x_2 * y_3 - x_3 * y_2) * x_2 + (x_0 * y_2 - x_1 * y_3 + x_2 * y_0 + x_3 * y_1) * x_1 + (x_0 * y_3 + x_1 * y_2 - x_2 * y_1 + x_3 * y_0) * x_0;
    q_rotatedi.textContent = result1;
    q_rotatedj.textContent = result2;
    q_rotatedk.textContent = result3;
}
```

CSS

```
#QuaternionversorImput {
    position: absolute;
    width: 250pt;
    top:  52.5pt;
    left: 10pt;
}
#Rotation {
    width: 250pt;
    position: absolute;
    top:  52.5pt;
    left: 260pt;
}
#RotatedQuaternionversor {
    height: 100pt;
    width: 125pt;
    position: absolute;
    top:  52.5pt;
    left: 510pt;
}
#RotatedQuaternionversorImi {
    height: 100pt;
    width: 125pt;
    position: absolute;
    top: 82pt;
    left: 560pt;
    font-size: 12pt;
}
#RotatedQuaternionversorImj {
    height: 100pt;
    width: 125pt;
    position: absolute;
    top: 110pt;
    left: 560pt;
    font-size: 12pt;
}
#RotatedQuaternionversorImk {
    height: 100pt;
    width: 125pt;
    position: absolute;
    top: 138pt;
    left: 560pt;
    font-size: 12pt;
}

#x {
    height: 100pt;
    width: 125pt;
    position: absolute;
    top: 82pt;
    left: 510pt;
    font-size: 12pt;
}
#y {
    height: 100pt;
    width: 125pt;
    position: absolute;
    top: 110pt;
    left: 510pt;
    font-size: 12pt;
}
#z {
    height: 100pt;
    width: 125pt;
    position: absolute;
    top: 138pt;
    left: 510pt;
    font-size: 12pt;
}
```

*free to use for everyone ;)*

Comment: Thank you so much; this helped tremendously! <3

Answer (score 3):

You are calculating $p\mathbf{x}p^{-1}$, the conjugation of $\mathbf{x}$ by $p$, where

$$ \mathbf{x}=0.15\mathbf{k}, \qquad p=0.86671-0.40654\mathbf{j}-0.21285\mathbf{j}+0.19555\mathbf{k}. $$

Since $p$ is a unit quaternion, $p^{-1}=\overline{p}=0.86671+0.40654\mathbf{j}+0.21285\mathbf{j}-0.19555\mathbf{k}$.

There are many packages in programming languages and computer algebra systems that let you do calculations like these with quaternions. I explain quaternions below.

---

A quaternion can be thought of as a scalar plus a 3D vector (also known as real and imaginary parts). The product of a scalar and a 3D vector is the usual scalar multiplication. The product of two vectors produces a quaternion with both scalar and vector components, given by (minus) the dot product and cross product respectively. In other words, for 3D vectors $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$, their quaternion product is

$$ \mathbf{uv}=-\mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{v}+\mathbf{u}\times\mathbf{v} $$

A fun way to think about this is that each of $\mathbf{i},\mathbf{j},\mathbf{k}$ is a square root of $-1$, and that multiplying two of them in cyclic order yields the third (e.g. $\mathbf{ij}=\mathbf{k}$) or out of order is the opposite (e.g. $\mathbf{ji}=-\mathbf{k}$). As a good exercise, you can discover the only square roots of $+1$ are $\pm1$; the square roots of $-1$ are any unit vector; two quaternions commute ($pq=qp$) if and only if their vector parts are parallel (i.e. scalar multiples of each other); and two quaternions anticommute ($qp=-pq$) if and only if they are perpendicular vectors.

The norm $|a+b\mathbf{i}+c\mathbf{j}+d\mathbf{k}|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2}$ is multiplicative, i.e. $|pq|=|p||q|$. The quaternion conjugate of $p=a+b\mathbf{i}+c\mathbf{j}+d\mathbf{k}$ is $\overline{p}=a-b\mathbf{i}-c\mathbf{j}-d\mathbf{k}$, i.e. the vector part is negated. This is useful in calculating the multiplicative inverse of a quaternion, $p^{-1}=\overline{p}/|p|^2$.

Because all unit vectors are square roots of $-1$, we have Euler's formula $\exp(\theta\mathbf{u})=\cos\theta+\sin\theta\,\mathbf{u}$, which means every quaternion has a polar form $p=r\exp(\theta\mathbf{u})$ where $r=|p|\ge0$ is the magnitude, $\mathbf{u}$ is the vector part of $p$ normalized to be a unit vector, and $0\le\theta\le\pi$ is a convex angle. You calculate the polar form just as you would for a complex number (after normalizing the vector part for $\mathbf{u}$). For nonreal quaternions the polar form is unique with $0<\theta<\pi$, otherwise for real nonzero quaternions, $\theta$ is $0$ or $\pi$ for positive/negative reals respectively, and $\mathbf{u}$ is an arbitrary unit vector.

Given a quaternion $p$, left-multiplication $L_p(x):=px$ and right-multiplication $R_p(x):=xp$ are linear transformations when considered as functions of $x$, if we treat the quaternions as a 4D real vector space. Because the norm is multiplicative, these are orthogonal transformations (aka linear isometries, or 4D rotations) for unit quaternions $p$ (i.e. with $|p|=1$).

If $\mathbf{u}$ is a unit vector, it can be extended to an orthonormal basis $\{\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w}\}$ with the same orientation as the standard basis $\{\mathbf{i},\mathbf{j},\mathbf{k}\}$ (i.e. $\mathbf{w}=\mathbf{u}\times\mathbf{v}$ according to the right-hand rule, just as $\mathbf{k}=\mathbf{i}\times\mathbf{j}$). Then $\{1,\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w}\}$ is an orthonormal basis for the quaternions as a real vector space. We can calculate the $4\times4$ matrix representing $L_p$ and $R_p$ with respect to this basis fairly easily; both are block-diagonal with two $2\times2$ blocks which are rotation matrices with angle $\theta$, except the second block of $R_p$ uses $-\theta$ instead of $\theta$.

The cumulative effect is that "conjugating" a quaternion by $p$, i.e. $(L_p\circ R_p^{-1})(x)=pxp^{=1}$ rotates in the $\mathbf{vw}$-plane by $2\theta$ and fixed the $1\mathbf{u}$-plane pointwise. In other words, if $\mathbf{x}$ is a 3D vector, then $p\mathbf{x}p^{-1}$ is a 3D vector which is the rotation of $\mathbf{x}$ around $\mathbf{u}$ by an angle of $2\theta$. The fact there is a "$2$" in this formula is a manifestation of **spin**. It implies every 3D rotation is represented by two antipodal unit quaternions $\pm p$.

Comment: It would probably be good to add that if you have a quaternion $n$, wich is not an unit quaternion, can convert it to a unit quaternion with $u = \frac{n}{|n|}$ where $u$ is the unit quaternion ... ;)

Answer (score 1):

A quaternion can be faithfully represented by a real $4\times 4$ matrix, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
\def\bbR#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}
\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{r}#1\end{array}\right]}
\def\v#1{\begin{Bmatrix}#1\end{Bmatrix}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\qif{\quad\iff\quad}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
q &= \v{s\\x\\y\\z} \qif
Q  = \m{
s&-x&-y&-z \\
x&s&-z&y \\
y&z&s&-x \\
z&-y&x&s \\
} \\
}$$
Note that $q$ appears in the first column of $Q$
and the conjugate $\:\bar q\iff Q^T$

You can now use ordinary matrix multiplication to address your problem:
$$\eqalign{
Q &= \m{
0.86671 & 0.40654 & 0.21285 & -0.19555 \\
-0.40654 & 0.86671 & -0.19555 & -0.21285 \\
-0.21285 & 0.19555 & 0.86671 & 0.40654 \\
0.19555 & 0.21285 & -0.40654 & 0.86671 \\
} \\
V &= \m{
0 & 0 & 0 & -0.15 \\
0 & 0 & -0.15 & 0 \\
0 & 0.15 & 0 & 0 \\
0.15 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
} \\
V_{rot} &= QVQ^T = \m{
0 & 0.07919 & -0.09322 & -0.08683 \\
\c{-0.07919} & 0 & -0.08683 & 0.09322 \\
\c{0.09322} & 0.08683 & 0 & 0.07919 \\
\c{0.08683} & -0.09322 & -0.07919 & 0 \\
} \\
}$$
The desired vector can be read from the $\c{\rm first}$ column of $V_{rot}$

A further advantage of the matrix representation becomes apparent when calculating quaternionic functions. Formulas for `exp(q)`, `log(q)`, `sqrt(q)`, etc are seemingly bespoke one-offs, whereas the theory of matrix functions is very mature and is a standard feature of programming languages like *Matlab* and *Julia*.